# Yii Multiple Dependent Dropdown

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu, yii

I'm new to Yii Framework. I'm making multiple dependent drop downs. 
Islands
Regions
Provinces
Cities

I have a dropdown of Islands, when you select an Islands, Regions dropdown list will be updated and only regions that belongs to that Island will appear. Same things goes to Provinces and Cities.

Now, I already finished Islands. When you select an Island, only Regions that belongs to that Island will be appear. My problem is the second level to down. When I select region, only provices that belongs to that region will appear. I have coded it the same way and logic as the first but I'm not getting any output or errors. I'm using Ajax. Can you help me? Thanks

Here's my VIEW

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'island'); ?>
    <?php
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'island',CHtml::listData(Islands::model()->findAll(), 'IslandID', 'IslandName'),
        array(
        'prompt'=>'Select Island',
        'ajax' => array(
        'type'=>'POST', 
        'url'=>CController::createUrl('loadRegions'), //or $this->createUrl('loadcities') if '$this' extends CController
        'update'=>'#region', //or 'success' => 'function(data){...handle the data in the way you want...}',
        'data'=>array('IslandID'=>'js:this.value'),
        ))
    );
    ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'region'); ?>
    <?php
        /*echo $form->dropDownList($model,'region',CHtml::listData(Regions::model()->findAll(), 'RegionID', 'RegionName'),
        array('class'=>'span4 chosen','maxlength'=>20)*/
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('region','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select Region'),
        array(
        'ajax' => array(
        'type'=>'POST', 
        'url'=>CController::createUrl('loadProvinces'), //or $this->createUrl('loadcities') if '$this' extends CController
        'update'=>'#province', //or 'success' => 'function(data){...handle the data in the way you want...}',
        'data'=>array('region'=>'js:this.value'),
        ))

    );

    ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'province'); ?>
    <?php
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('province','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select Province'));
    ?>  
</div>
```

Here's my Controller

```
/* Function for dependent dropdown */
public function actionLoadRegions()
{

   $data=Regions::model()->findAll('IslandID=:IslandID', 
   array(':IslandID'=>(int) $_POST['IslandID']));

   $data=CHtml::listData($data,'RegionID','RegionName');

   foreach($data as $value=>$region)
   echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($region),true);
}

public function actionLoadProvinces()
{
    //var_dump($_POST['region']);

    $data=Provinces::model()->findAll('RegionID=:RegionID', 
    array(':RegionID'=>(int) $_POST['RegionID']));

   $data=CHtml::listData($data,'ProvinceID','ProvinceName');

   foreach($data as $value=>$province)
   echo CHtml::tag('option',                         array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($province),true);
}
```

I just followed this but on Multiple Dropdowns, seems it doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: there should be some error,if you are using chrome just see in network tab of developers tool window and change first dropdown and then second... ajax call to controller success or fail will be shown

Comment: Yes. I tried it but I'm not getting any errors :(

Comment: in your region dropdown modify `'data'=>array('region'=>'js:this.value')` to `'data'=>array('RegionID'=>'js:this.value')`

Comment: I tried it also but still doesn't work and no errors or whatsoever :(

Comment: http://codingbin.com/dependent-drop-down-lists-in-yii/ check this if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'region',array(),array(prompt'=>'Select Region'),'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST', 
    'url'=>CController::createUrl('loadProvinces'), //or $this->createUrl('loadcities') if '$this' extends CController
    'data'=>array('region'=>'js:this.value'),
    'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'province'),
          )
        )); ?>
```

Also

```
  <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'province', array(),array('prompt'=>'Choose Province')); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't work too. I'm wondering why my ajax request is cannot be seen. I'm trying to see the value $_POST of my region dropdown and no errors and no output :(

Comment: Juz try by giving listdata to your dropdown and see ajax is getting triggerd.

Comment: I meant replace `array()` with `CHtml::listData(Regions::model()->findAll()`.Try and see whether ajax is wrkng o not!

Comment: It is working. Regions List is populated depending on Values on Islands list. My problem is Provices, when I choose any Regions, Provinces doesn't change, I can't even see an error or firebug :(

Comment: seems like u have a format error in your dropdowns. try my updated answer

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still doesn't work. Yeah I think I'm having problem with formatting, When I changed to this format ajax request can be read.

    
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'island',CHtml::listData(Islands::model()->findAll(), 'IslandID', 'IslandName');

Comment: But cannot use that format because i don't want to pull all records on provinces because it should be populated based on regions selected.

Answer (score 0):

Example program, similar to your requirement.

Below are  **Islands**, **Regions**, **Provinces** tables

*Islands table*

```
 Islands
 -------
 IslandID
 IslandName
```

*Regions table*

```
 Regions
 ---------
 RegionID
 RegionName
 IslandID
```

*Provinces table*

```
 Provinces
 ----------
 ProvinceID
 ProvinceName
 IslandID
 RegionID
```

Assume that i'm programming user registration. So, `$model` is an instance/object of `User` model

*My View*

```
 Select Island 
 <?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'IslandID',CHtml::listData(Islands::model()->findAll(), 'IslandID', 'IslandName'),
     array(
        'prompt'=>'Select Island',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST', //My method type
            'url' => CController::createUrl('myController/LoadRegions'), //This is my request/ajax URL
            array('IslandID'=>'js:this.value'), //I'm passing the selected dropdonw value.
            'dataType' => 'JSON', 
            'success'=>'js:function(data)' //The functionaliy after success
            . '{'
            . '    var html="";'
            . '    $.each(data,function(i,obj)'
            . '    {'
            . '         html+="<option value=obj.RegionID>"+obj.RegionName+"</option>"'
            . '    });'
            . '    $("#User_RegionID").html(html);' //ID of regions dropdown list
            . '}' 

    )));
);
?>

Select Region
<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList($model,'RegionID', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select Region'));
?>
```

For this dropDownlist id will be generated as User_RegionID. ie, A feild id will be generated with combination of Model name and field name centering with underscore "_".

**EX:**

1. ModelName_FieldName
2. City_Id (City is Model and Id is property/field in the City model)

Controller Method

```
public function actionLoadRegions()
{

    $IslandID=$_POST['IslandID'];

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select=array('RegionID,RegionName');
    $criteria->condition='IslandID='.$IslandID;
    $criteria->order='RegionName';
    $RegionsAry= Regions::model()->findAll($criteria);

    $ary=array();
    foreach($RegionsAry as $i=>$obj)
    {
         $ary[$i]['RegionID']=$obj->RegionID;
         $ary[$i]['RegionName']=$obj->RegionName;            
    }
    echo json_encode($ary);
}
```

To get the Provinces list on selecting Regions

```
Select Region
<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList($model,'RegionID', array(),
array(
  'prompt'=>'Select Region'
  'ajax' => array(
       'type' => 'POST', //My method type
       'url' => CController::createUrl('myController/LoadProvinces'), //This is my request/ajax URL
       array('RegionID'=>'js:this.value'), //I'm passing the selected dropdonw value.
            'dataType' => 'JSON', 
            'success'=>'js:function(data)' //The functionaliy after success
            . '{'
            . '    var html="";'
            . '    $.each(data,function(i,obj)'
            . '    {'
            . '         html+="<option value=obj.ProvinceID>"+obj.ProvinceName+"</option>"'
            . '    });'
            . '    $("#User_ProvinceID").html(html);' //ID of Province dropdown list
            . '}' 
));
?>

Select Provinces
<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList($model,'ProvinceID', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select Province'));
?>
```

Controller method to get all Provinces

```
public function actionLoadProvinces()
{
     //To your task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no problem in controller file. I think you have problem in **view file**. Especially, in your **Select Region Part**. Here is my updated code of your view file. Please delete 1 argument array() and check it.

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'region'); ?>
<?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'region',CHtml::listData(Regions::model()->findAll(), 'RegionID', 'RegionName'),
    array('class'=>'span4 chosen','maxlength'=>20)*/
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('region','', array('prompt'=>'Select Region'),**//Here i remove array() and it works.**
    array(
    'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST', 
    'url'=>CController::createUrl('loadProvinces'), //or $this->createUrl('loadcities') if '$this' extends CController
    'update'=>'#province', //or 'success' => 'function(data){...handle the data in the way you want...}',
    'data'=>array('region'=>'js:this.value'),
    ))

);

?>
```